# EACCES: permission denied, rmdir 'build'

Tags: node.js

I'm attempting to install nodehun.

I get the following error after researching and debugging for 5 hours:

> nodehun@2.0.12 install /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/nodehun
>   node-gyp rebuild
>
> gyp ERR! clean error  gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied,
>   rmdir 'build' gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-29-generic gyp ERR! command
>   "/usr/bin/node"
>   "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
>   "rebuild" gyp ERR! cwd
>   /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/nodehun
>   gyp ERR! node -v v9.11.2 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2 gyp ERR! not ok 
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! nodehun@2.0.12
>   install: `node-gyp rebuild` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!  npm ERR!
>   Failed at the nodehun@2.0.12 install script. npm ERR! This is probably
>   not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output
>   above.

I don't know where 'build' is or why sudo or chown will not fix this error. Please help.

Comment: remove your node_modules and Delete your $HOME/.node-gyp directory and try again.
did you installed build-essential ? if not then do that.


"sudo apt-get install build-essential"